# trying to insert json with php

Tags: php, json

below i have my json structure, what i'm trying to do at the moment, is insert new fields, with their own values, and i can't think of a way to do this in php. so far i have :

```
//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('sleaderboard.json');

//convert json object to php associative array
$outdata = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$encdata = json_encode($indata);
$uname = $_POST["username"];

$indata = $uname . '{' . $encdata . '}';

file_put_contents('sleaderboard.json', $indata);
?>
```

which seems to almost work, but deletes the old data. anybody got help? PS: $indata is just elements passed through post, collected earlier in the code.

```
{
    "clarke": {
        "name": "clarke",
        "comment": "comments test",
        "score": 6
    },
    "sam": 
    {
        "name": "sam",
        "comment": "insert regular comment here",
        "score": 0
    },
    "test":
    {
        "name": "test",
        "comment": "boring, normal, extremely generic comment",
        "score": 7
    }
}
```

Comment: don't do json by hand, just get the file, decode, push new element inside an array, encode, put inside the file

Comment: why not add the `$indata` to `$outdata` and then save the `$outdata`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you want to append into file.

```
file_put_contents('sleaderboard.json', $indata, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: that would've helped. anywho, i did find a solution. using different functions, and just editing the outdata array